# Derivative of absolute value over the complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Given the function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, z \mapsto z\bar{z}$. I am supposed to determine where f is differentiable and where it is holomorphic. So I tested the Cauchy Riemann Differential equations and found out that for $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2,v(x,y)=0$ we have $ D_xu(x,y)=2x=D_yv(x,y) \Leftrightarrow x=0$ and $ D_yu(x,y)=2x=-D_xv(x,y) \Leftrightarrow y=0$. So $(0,0)$ is the only candidate where it might be differentiable and since the partial derivatives entering the CR differential equations are continous, f is actually differentiable there. Is this correct? So f appears to be nowhere holomorphic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. The function is (complex-) differentiable only at $z=0$ and nowhere holomorphic. You can check the differentiability at $z=0$ directly by computing
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h\bar h}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \bar h = 0.$$

(Note that Cauchy-Riemann's equations can be satsified at a single point, even if the function is not differentiable there, but since $u$ and $v$ are $C^1$, this is not a problem here.)